# Windows to RHEL 6 File copy - mount error 13 = Permission denied

Tags: rhel, mount

I am fairly new to linux Administration for forgive me if I say anything that sounds crazy or if this question has been asked before.  I did a search on the StackExchange and Unix & Linux site but could not find a helpful solution.

I have a RHEL 6 server that I just hardened using the CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Benchmark v1.3.0

I need to move files from a Win8 machine to the RHEL 6 Server.

I have performed the following as root:

- Installed samba and cifs Util
- I created the directory /mnt/winshare
- I performed chmod 755 /mnt/winshare
        drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jun  9 12:43 winshare
- I created a share on the win8 box.  Permissions for share & folder are set to for Everyone-Full (I know this isn't a best practice but trying to get this to work)

I have run the following command:

mount -t cifs -o username="/rhel /mnt/winshare

with these results:

Password: 
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Not sure where I am going wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Everyone" on Windows means everyone who can authenticate. You need to provide a username and password to authenticate.

Comment: Mount it from the Windows side where you are already authenticated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jordanm. I have a username and get prompted for a PW.  It is my regular user acct so I know the credentials are correct.

How would I mount this from the Windows Side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per a RHEL Support Tech:

We strongly recommend updating to the latest kernel and cifs-utils package to mount shares on Windows 8 and newer systems as there's been many improvements made to CIFS in these packages since RHEL's 6.0 release.

However, first I'd suggest trying the ntlmssp security mode, which may be required by Windows 8. This is available in two forms, depending on if the Windows system requires packet signing, if you're not sure you can try both with no worries:

## mount -t cifs -o username=x,sec=ntlmssp /rhel /mnt/winshare

## mount -t cifs -o username=x,sec=ntlmsspi /rhel /mnt/winshare

This is the one that worked for me:

## mount -t cifs -o username=x,sec=ntlmsspi /IP/sharename /mnt/winshare